Question about the meaning of logical implication
So, I came across the following equivalence:
$$(p \to q) \equiv (\neg p \lor q)$$
Which I had been knowing for a while, but I never quite understood. I understand when it's used this way: I assert $p \land (p\to q)$, it follows that $q$. In other words, asserting $p \to q$ is like saying "if $p$, then $q$".
But I fail to understand it the other way: if $p$ and $q$ are both true, then $p \to q$. So if Eminem's name is Marshall and the Sun is bigger than Earth, can I rightly state that Eminem being named Marshall implies that the Sun is bigger than the Earth? If this is true, does this mean that logical implication doesn't describe causality?
From my (little) understanding, there's a substancial difference between $\vdash$ and $\to$, but I think I can't quite grasp it. Maybe $\vdash$ is the causality connective I'm looking for?

Certainly, ordinary logical implication does not mean causality. Nor does entailment. They are only concerned with whether you can conclude the result from the premise, not (in some physical sense) why.

$\vdash$ is derivability $\vDash$ is logical consequnce and $\to$ is the conditional connective.

See here

This question gets asked all the time here. You'll find a lot of the posts if you search for "implication truth table".

The logical connective $\to$ expresses the material implication .. this is not the same as logical implication. And neither of these means any kind of causal connection.

You are right that logical implication does not describe causality.
In natural language $p\rightarrow q$ means "whenever $p$ is true, it follows that $q$ is true".
So if $q$ is always true, then $p\rightarrow q$ is always true.
For example, the following statements are both true:

If Eminem is called Marshall, then the Sun is bigger than the Earth.
If Eminem is not called Marshall, then the Sun is bigger than the Earth.

Lets look at the symbols you mention:
The symbols $P\vdash q$ mean that from a set of propositions $P$ you can derive the statement $q$, using deduction rules such as modus ponens. So $\vdash$ doesn't care whether anything is true, only whether it is  provable.
Meanwhile, $p\rightarrow q$ is a proposition in a formal language. The symbol $\rightarrow$ is a connective, which we would like to play nicely with the truth-values we are going to assign to the propositions. It is often introduced using a truth-table.
The closest thing to a "causality" connective is probably $
\vDash$ (though I would not normally describe it as a connective).
If we write $P\vDash q$ we mean that if all propositions in the set $P$ are true in a given model, then the proposition $q$ is necessarily true in that model too.

There are connections between these symbols. For example the Deduction Lemma lets us exchange $\vdash$ and $\rightarrow$ in some circumstances.
$$ \{p\}\cup P \vdash q \iff P\vdash p\rightarrow q$$
The interplay between $\vdash$ and $\vDash$ leads to the discussion of completeness and soundness in logic, and may be of interest to you.

So I can consider the set $P$ which only contains the proposition $p$: "Eminem's name is Marshall" and the proposition $q$: "the Sun is bigger than the Earth" and it would be false that $P \vDash q$, even though $p \to q$?
Also, I don't quite understand the difference between $\vdash$ and $\vDash$. Can you explain further, please? Maybe add an example where they yield different results? If it isn't a bother.

The difference between them appears more often in the context of formal logic. When discussing the real world, it doesn't really make sense to use $\vdash$ or $\vDash$. They're very specific symbols defined for the context of a logical theory.
Now that I think about it, a more philosophical approach might be more helpful for you, have a look at material implication.

Yeah I had read that already, it clarified things a bit. So what should I use to mean causality? $\vDash$, as you said? But then why isn't it used to describe the real world?

Although there are limits to "causality" being interpreted as $\models$.  For instance, consider a physical experiment with a fixed circuit of a power supply, a switch, and a light bulb.  Then "light is on" $\models$ "switch is closed", but it would be strange to say "the light being on caused the switch to be closed" rather than the other way around.

I don't think there are any mathematical symbols that appropriate to describe causality. For me, one of mathematics' biggest selling points is that it is acausal.

@Elvis I am having trouble thinking of a short example of when $\vdash$ and $\vDash$ differ. The simplest example is that if $p$ is not provable then $P\vdash p$ is false, even though there can be models where $P\vDash p$.

This question has a nice example.

@Numeral ah, I get it. Thanks.


So, I came across the following equivalence:
$$(p \to q) \equiv (\neg p \lor q)$$

IMO more intuitive would be:
$$(p \to q) \equiv \neg (p \land \neg q)$$
Example
Consider the implication, it is raining ($R$) implies it is cloudy ($C$)
$$R\to C$$
This does not mean that rain causes cloudiness. It also does not mean that it is always cloudy when it is raining (e.g. so-called sunshowers). It simply rules out the possibility that it is currently both raining AND not cloudy (present tense). This is entirely consistent with the usual truth table** for implication in classical logic:

Note the following:

When $R$ is true and $R\to C$ is true (line 1), then $C$ is true. (The Rule of Detachment)
When $R$ is false (lines 3-4), then $R\to C$ is true regardless of the
truth value of $C$. (The Principle of Vacuous Truth.)
This form of argument is rarely if ever used in daily discourse since
we rarely consider that the implications of a proposition known to be
false. It is, however, routinely used in very technical arguments,
e.g. in mathematical proofs.

You also wrote:

So if Eminem's name is Marshall and the Sun is bigger than Earth, can
I rightly state that Eminem being named Marshall implies that the
Sun is bigger than the Earth?

Correct. In other words, it is not the case that both (1) Eminem is named Marshall AND (2) the Sun is not bigger than the earth.

** Text version of truth table:
R C R=>C
T T T
T F F
F T T
F F T
